# Module import fails unless in current directory - Python3

Tags: python, facebook, python-3.x, python-module

I have written a small Facebook OAUTH function that I want to use as a module whenever I need to generate a token to post to my FB feed or page. The problem is unless I'm in the directory that `fb_auth` is in I can't call the module.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

''' Facebook authorization module'''

import requests
import os

def get_token(app_id, app_secret):
    payload = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'client_id': app_id, 'client_secret': app_secret}
    response = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?', params=payload)
    result = eval(response.text)
    token = result['access_token']
    return token


if __name__ == '__main__':

    get_token()
```

So when i'm in the working directory (`/home/scripts/python/fb_auth/`)the module will import and function as it's supposed to:

```
>>> from fb_auth import get_token
>>> import os
>>> home = os.environ['HOME']
>>> work = home + '/scripts/python/'
>>> keys = work + 'apikeys'
>>> with open (keys, 'r') as f:
...    keys = eval(f.read())
... 
>>> app_id = keys['fb_keys']['riverwarn']['app_id']
>>> app_secret = keys['fb_keys']['riverwarn']['app_secret']
>>> get_token(app_id, app_secret)
'194XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXY_OM'
```

However, if I'm not in the working directory (`/home/scripts/python/`) I get nothing:

```
>>> import fb_auth
>>> fb_auth.get_token(app_id, app_secret)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'fb_auth' has no attribute 'get_token'

>>> from fb_auth import get_token

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_token'
```

Do I need to put this in the *main* Python modules folder to make this work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't find it because it doesn't appear in the sys.path.
You can add it to the sys.path by installing it.
See full documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/install/#how-installation-works

Comment: Thanks Eran. I've only been learning Python about 6 months and I'm not real familiar with the system operations. Your suggestion is exactly what I was looking for.